# Retrieve different images from SQL DB using a button

Tags: c#, sql, image

I am trying to retrieve images from my sql database, I just did :

```
cs.Open(); // open the connection
string sqlquery = "SELECT Pic_path FROM Picture WHERE ID='" + Land_ID + "'";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, cs);
SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();
while (sdr.Read())
{ 
    Panel1.BackImageUrl = sdr["Pic_path"].ToString(); 
}
cs.Close();
```

But I want to now how can I retrieve different image from Picture table whenever I click a button, for example a next button?

can any one help me ASAP ?

Answer (score 2):

Your event handler for the button click would simply need to increment `Land_ID` to the next valid ID and then run the query again.

And, on another note, please don't build dynamic queries like that. They leave you open to all kinds of fun attacks. You should use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) instead.